# Tuning/Best Practices Inetsoft Style Report BI Tool?

Tags: tomcat, db2, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

Is anyone using the business intelligence tool Inetsoft Style Report ?  I'm stuck with it and was wondering if anyone has advice on tuning and/or best practices for server admin?  We are running on a fast Solaris box using Tomcat with a db2 database.

Answer (score 3):

You have my sympathy. We run ours on a dual Xeon with 4G ram, and it's still a pig. One of our programmers is an ex-Inetsoft employee and has done everything known to optimize it.

My only suggestion is if your organization is considering StyleReport, run!

Answer (score 1):

Jim & Clint,

This is Mark from InetSoft. Sorry to hear of performance issues. This is definitely the type of thing our Support team can help with. So please reach out to your InetSoft account manager or log a ticket at http://www.inetsoft.com/customer/support.jsp . The next versions of Style Intelligence and Style Report come out this month, and performance enhancements are on the list of advances.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can check is whether the CPU is fully utilized when the server is running. If it's not at or close to 100%, check the Tomcat thread pool size and try increase it. There should be parameters in StyleReport to control it's thread pool sizes too. Normally if the CPUs are fully utilized, the performance should be ok.